# Swift Array filter very slow performance

Tags: arrays, swift

I have 2 arrays of Strings `beforeStringList` and `afterStringList`. These are actually representations of sqlite tables, and my end goal is to get a list of the items that are only present in 1 of the arrays so I can tell if something was added or removed. So as an example if an element exists in `beforeStringList` and not `afterStringList` then it was removed and so on. My logic was to just compare the arrays and use the `.contains` operation to see if one array contains the item or not. However, this takes a very long time. On the order of many minutes, which is not going to work. `beforeStringList` and `afterStringList` each contain about 100k items.

This is how I am attempting to run this:

```
DispatchQueue.global().async {
                
     var output = beforeStringList.filter{afterStringList.contains($0) == false}

}
```

I also tried using a `set` which was no different in terms of performance:

```
var set = Set(beforeStringList.map {$0})

DispatchQueue.global().async {
            
         var rowsAdded = set.filter { row in
               
              if afterStringList.contains(row) == false{
                    print("row: \(row)")
         }
                
         return true
     }

}
```

Open to all ideas for how to improve this!

Comment: `.contains(row)`, that what should take time. Since order doesn't seem to bother you, what about using two `Set`? There are useful methods on it, with `intersect`, `substract`, etc.

Comment: Also, are you measuring in an optimized release build? Debug builds are much slower.

Comment: You're using the Set wrong, so you're getting quadratic time complexity. The Set is _slower_ to iterate over than an Array. Its benefit is to give faster `contains` checks. You should be iterating over an `beforeStringList: Array`, checking `contains` against a `afterStringList: Set`. Better yet, use the Set methods like Larme said, which do this correctly.

Comment: Wouldn’t it be better to do this at a database level?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tested on a "macOS Command App" with a simple Run.

Here is the code I tested:

```
var beforeStringList: [String] = []
var afterStringList: [String] = []

for _ in 0...10000 {
    beforeStringList.append("\(Int.random(in: 0...10000))")
    afterStringList.append( "\(Int.random(in: 0...10000))")
}

//Testing Initial code: ie Array.filter() and Array.contains()
var startDate = Date()
var output1 = beforeStringList.filter {
    afterStringList.contains($0) == false
}
print("Array.filter() and Array.contains(): \(Date().timeIntervalSince(startDate))")

//Testing with using a Set for the beforeList: ie Set.filter() and Array.contains()
startDate = Date()
var beforeSet = Set(beforeStringList)
var output2 = beforeSet.filter { afterStringList.contains($0) == false }
print("Set.filter() and Array.contains(): \(Date().timeIntervalSince(startDate))")

//Testing with using a Set for the afterList: Array.filter() and Set.contains()
startDate = Date()
var afterSet = Set(afterStringList)
var output3 = beforeStringList.filter { afterSet.contains($0) == false }
print("Array.filter() and Set.contains(): \(Date().timeIntervalSince(startDate))")

//Testing with using a Set for the beforeList and afterList: Set.subtract()
startDate = Date()
beforeSet = Set(beforeStringList)
afterSet = Set(afterStringList)
var output4 = beforeSet.subtracting(afterSet)
print("Set.subtract(): \(Date().timeIntervalSince(startDate))")

//Testing with using a Set for the beforeList: Set.subtract()
startDate = Date()
beforeSet = Set(beforeStringList)
var output5 = beforeSet.subtracting(afterStringList)
print("Set.subtract() on array: \(Date().timeIntervalSince(startDate))")

print("--- Verifications ---")
print("Verifying output2")
print(Set(output1) == Set(output2))
print("Verifying output 3")
print(Set(output1) == Set(output3))
print("Verifying output 4")
print(Set(output1) == Set(output4))
print("Verifying output 5")
print(Set(output1) == Set(output5))
print("--- end ---")
```

I got different outputs, but here's one of them:

```
$>Array.filter() and Array.contains(): 3.4921441078186035
$>Set.filter() and Array.contains(): 2.178665041923523
$>Array.filter() and Set.contains(): 0.0021200180053710938
$>Set.subtract(): 0.002646923065185547
$>Set.subtract() on array: 0.0021669864654541016
$>--- Verifications ---
$>Verifying output2
$>true
$>Verifying output 3
$>true
$>Verifying output 4
$>true
$>Verifying output 5
$>true
```

So let's analyze the initial code:

```
array1.filter { array2.contains($0) } //simplified
```

So `Array.filter()` does an iteration on each elements of `array1`, and `array2` is iterated (from `1` to `array2.count`, or less if element if found before, considered as 1 full iteration). So the `Array.contains()` was the part slowing down your code.

Then you went on using a `Set` instead of `array1`, but the operation still takes time, as a `Set` is "optimized" for `Set.contains()`. So the "reverse" (`Array.filter()` + `Set.contains()` is quicker).

From there, you can use `Set`, but then, go full `Set` and use the `Set` methods. In your case, you want to use `Set.subtract()`

Now, according to these infos, we might say: Let's use `Set.subtractOnArray()` (where `subtractOnArray()` is `Set.subtract()` with an Array Parameter) or `Array.filter()` + `Set.contains()` combo, but the truth might lies in-between. No? Why does `Set.subtract()` is slower than if all we said before that it's "optimized" for `Set.contains()` and such?

I always set `startDate = Date()` **BEFORE** the conversion from `Array` to `Set`.
If I put it afterwards, focusing only the in `Array.filter()`, `Set.filter()`,`Array.contains()`, `Set.contains()`,`Set.subtract()`, `Set.subtractOnArray()`, another sample output would be:

```
$>Array.filter() and Array.contains(): 3.4415539503097534
$>Set.filter() and Array.contains(): 2.1599819660186768
$>Array.filter() and Set.contains(): 0.0010540485382080078
$>Set.subtract(): 0.00034797191619873047
$>Set.subtract() on array: 0.0010139942169189453
```

And there, we see the full victory of `subtract()`.

Indeed, depending on your data, the `Array` to `Set` conversion might take some time. It all depends then on which part you want to optimize, your use-cases and especially: does it matter as this point. If something takes "0.0003" seconds or "0.002" seconds, will I really see it?

Now, I assumed the order didn't matter, in which case the output is "unordered", in which case you might want to use `NSMutableOrderedSet` or Swift version in [Swift-Collections `OrderedSet`](https://github.com/apple/swift-collections/blob/main/Documentation/OrderedSet.md). There is no "subtract", but you might find your way there.

Comment: Excellent answer, as usual. A minor nit: You have a typo in your logging code. It should probably read `print("Set.subtract()...` rather than `print("Set.substract()...`. (I was a little confused at first.)

Comment: Indeed. After a quick search, `substract` did exist in English until 18th Century due to French influence, and since I'm French, my native language is still influencing my English in the 21th ^^

Comment: Good point about including the conversion to a set in your time comparisons. I tend to enclose every part of both approaches I'm comparing in my timing blocks anyway, but I hadn't specifically thought about the cost of converting arrays to sets. In many cases I expect that to be swamped by the savings, since `contains()` is an `O(n)` operation on arrays, and looping through arrays with contains becomes `O(n²)` (which is to say the performance SUCKS.)

Comment: Thank you for the very detailed explanation, I appreciate it. I am going to take a shot at this approach.

Answer (score -2):

```
DispatchQueue.global().async {
    let afterSet = Set(afterStringList)
    var output = beforeStringList.filter { !afterSet.contains($0) }
    // Now 'output' contains items that are in 'beforeStringList' but not in 'afterStringList'
}
```